# git-svn broken on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, git-svn, osx-mavericks

I am having some serious issue with git-svn. Until I did not update to Mac OS X Maverick, it all worked fine (source tree and git svn command line) but now there are following errors while I try to checkout a svn repository:

On command line :

```
 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
 Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/../Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/../Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

error: git-svn died of signal 5

http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/08/21/solving-symbol-not-found-perlgthrkeyptr-when-running-git-svn-certain-unnamed-operating-sy
```

When trying to checkout using Sourcetree:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree svn clone SVN_PATH /Users/myusername/XCodeWorkspace/NewFolder 
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl     /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl     /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Editor.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Editor.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 81.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 81.
Completed with errors, see above
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and managed to solve it? I tried the following solution:
http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/08/21/solving-symbol-not-found-perlgthrkeyptr-when-running-git-svn-certain-unnamed-operating-sy
But it did not solve the issue.

P.S. I have 2 XCodes installed. /Application/XCode.app and /Application/XCode5 and in command line I have selected first path which is Xcode 4.6.3 (using xcode-select).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It got resolved when I upgraded the Xcode version to 5.0.2.

Answer (score -3):

I just received this same thing.  In my case I updated from Lion to Mavericks.

I don't actually need Xcode (just the command-line tools... I actually build my own compilers, etc.) so I just did this:

sudo rm -rf /Applications/XCode.app

That fixed it...

I don't know if that's a viable fix for you or not though...

Comment: That is surely not the solution.